# Can a space $X$ be homeomorphic to its twofold product with itself, $X \times X$?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, product-space

Let $X$ be  a  topological  space  of  infinite  cardinality. Is  it  possible  for  any  $X$  to  be  homeomorphic  to  $X\times X$  $?$

For example, $\mathbb R$  is  not  homeomorphic  to  $\mathbb R^{2}$, and $S^{1}$  is not  homeomorphic  to  $S^{1} \times S^{1}$ . What  other  topological  spaces  might we consider$?$ What  properties  of  a  space  may  ensure  or  contradict  this  possibility$?$  From  the  little  topology  I  have  learnt  yet,  I  have  not  seen  this  happening.

Comment: $X = Y^{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: Other common nontrivial examples include $\mathbb Q$ and the Cantor set.

Comment: @MikeMiller What is the argument for $\Bbb Q$, say? At a glance this seems nonobvious, assuming that $\Bbb Q$ is given the subspace topology induced by its inclusion into $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Travis: There is a general theorem of Sierpinski: a countable space with no isolated points is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. But I believe you can write down an explicit homeomorphism with continued fraction trickery. I believe this is done somewhere on this site.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks, that's quite a nice result. A little searching yields this well-sourced answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/56536/155629 . Sierpinski's original paper (in French) is http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm1/fm113.pdf .

Comment: (@MikeMiller FWIW, that post also includes metrizability among the hypotheses of Sierpinski's Theorem.)

Comment: @Travis: Ah, fair point. You need some decent hypothesis since it's obviously false if you allow non-Hausdorff spaces. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: See also:
[Homeomorphism between Space and Product](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677574/homeomorphism-between-space-and-product),
[Homeomorphism between topological space and product space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722412/homeomorphism-between-topological-space-and-product-space),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this level of generality you can make $X=X \times X$ happen quite easily. Take a discrete space of any infinite cardinality, for instance. Or topologize $X=A^B$ by whatever means and compare $X \times X = A^{B \sqcup B}$; under various mild assumptions on $B$ those spaces would be homeomorphic.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, consider $X := \Bbb Z$ endowed with the discrete topology.

For any topological manifold $M$, $\dim (M \times M) = \dim M + \dim M = 2 \dim M$. Since the dimension of a nonempty topological manifold is well-defined, there is no positive-dimensional topological manifold $M$ for which $M \cong M \times M$, which in particular excludes $R$ and $S^1$ as observed. This implies that the example $X = \Bbb Z$ is the only example that is a (second countable) topological manifold.

Comment: Here, well defined means that homeomorphic topological manifolds have the same dimension?

Comment: @Augustin: The definition of dimension of a topological manifold is the unique integer $n$ such that $M$ is locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. That this is well-defined comes down to that $n$ being unique: that is, that $\Bbb R^n \cong \Bbb R^m$ implies $ n=m$.

Answer (score 4):

Many Banach spaces are *linearly* homeomorphic to their Cartesian squares. For instance all classical spaces including $c_0$, $\ell_\infty$, $C(K)$ for $K$ compact metric, $L_p(\mu)$ for $p\in [1,\infty]$ etc.